# Retrieve the country from the geographical locations in Python

Tags: python, geocoding

I am trying to get the country name from the latitude and longitude points from my pandas dataframe.
Currently I have used geolocator.reverse(latitude,longitude) to get the full address of the geographic location.  But there is no option to retrieve the country name from the full address as it returns a list.

Method used:

```
 def get_country(row):
     pos = str(row['StartLat']) + ', ' + str(row['StartLong'])
     locations = geolocator.reverse(pos)
     return locations
```

Call to get_country by passing the dataframe:

```
df4['country'] = df4.apply(lambda row: get_country(row), axis = 1)
```

Current output:

```
StartLat                  StartLong           Address          
52.509669              13.376294          Potsdamer Platz, Mitte, Berlin, Deutschland, Europe
```

Just wondering whether there is some Python library to retrieve the country when we pass the geographic points.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can't you split address and get element from list - ie. `"Potsdamer Platz, Mitte, Berlin, Deutschland, Europ".split(", ")[-2]`

Comment: what module do you use ?

Comment: @furas: I currently use geolocator.reverse()

Comment: I didn't ask for function name but module name - `geopy`, `geocoder`, other. But I see you get answer.

Comment: Could you post the code where you initialize `geolocator`?

Comment: @EvanGiesel: I have not initialised it anywhere in my code. I am just importing and directly using it.

Comment: @user3447653 ok, could you post the line where you import it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `get_country` function, your return value `location` will have an attribute `raw`, which is a dict that looks like this:

```
{
  'address': {
     'attraction': 'Potsdamer Platz',
     'city': 'Berlin',
     'city_district': 'Mitte',
     'country': 'Deutschland',
     'country_code': 'de',
     'postcode': '10117',
     'road': 'Potsdamer Platz',
     'state': 'Berlin'
   },
   'boundingbox': ['52.5093982', '52.5095982', '13.3764983', '13.3766983'],
   'display_name': 'Potsdamer Platz, Mitte, Berlin, 10117, Deutschland',
   ... and so one ...
}
```

so `location.raw['address']['country']` gives `'Deutschland'`

If I read your question correctly, a possible solution could be:

```
def get_country(row):
    pos = str(row['StartLat']) + ', ' + str(row['StartLong'])
    locations = geolocator.reverse(pos)
    return location.raw['address']['country']
```

EDIT: The format of the location.raw object will differ depending on which geolocator service you are using. My example uses geopy.geocoders.Nominatim, from the example on [geopy's documentation site](http://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-geopy.geocoders), so your results might differ.

Comment: I believe the API no longer returns an `address` in the `raw` attribute of the location returned

Comment: Thank for the answer. If we try to extract the address from 70k unique geolocation I am getting time out and HTTP Error 502: Bad Gateway. Do you have any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

My code,hopefully that helps:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim 
nm = Nominatim()

place, (lat, lng) = nm.geocode("3995 23rd st, San Francisco,CA 94114")
print('Country' + ": " + place.split()[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what service you're using with geopy, but as a small plug which I'm probably biased towards, this I think could be a simpler solution for you.

https://github.com/Ziptastic/ziptastic-python

```py
from ziptastic import Ziptastic

# Set API key.
api = Ziptastic('<your api key>')
result = api.get_from_coordinates('42.9934', '-84.1595')
```

Which will return a list of dictionaries like so:

```
[
    {
        "city": "Owosso",
        "geohash": "dpshsfsytw8k",
        "country": "US",
        "county": "Shiawassee",
        "state": "Michigan",
        "state_short": "MI",
        "postal_code": "48867",
        "latitude": 42.9934,
        "longitude": -84.1595,
        "timezone": "America/Detroit"
    }
]
```